# arma::rowvec from std::vector<int>

Tags: c++, std, armadillo

I have an std::vector and I want to convert it into a arma::rowvec

I've done:

```
vector<int> x = foo();
rowvec a;

vector<int>::const_iterator iter2;
int j = 0;
for(iter2 = x.begin(); iter2 != x.end(); ++iter2) {
    a(j++,0) =  *iter2; 
}
a.print("a");
```

but I get:

```
error: Mat::operator(): out of bounds

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():
```

If instead of `a(j++,0) =  *iter2;` I use `a << *iter2;` in final rowvec, I get only the last element.

Answer (score 10):

Recent versions of Armadillo are able to construct matrix/vector objects directly from instances of std::vector.

For example:

```
std::vector<double> X(5);

// ... process X ...

arma::vec Y(X);
arma::mat M(X);
```

Answer (score 9):

You forgot to set the size of the row vector.

A more correct code would be:

```
vector<int> x = foo();
rowvec a(x.size());
... rest of your code ...
```

It's also possible to convert a std::vector to an Armadillo matrix or vector via the  [conv_to](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#conv_to) function. So instead of doing a manual loop, you can do this:

```
vector<int> x = foo();
rowvec a = conv_to<rowvec>::from(x);
```

Note that *rowvec* is a synonym for *Row<double>*.  See the documentation for the [Row](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Row) class. As such, in both code examples there is also an *int* to *double* conversion occurring. If you don't want that, you may wish to use *irowvec* instead.

Answer (score 2):

Using the constructor that takes an aux_mem pointer?

```
 rowvec a(x.pointer, x.size());
```

Comment: this say me: ‘invalid use of std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::pointer’

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
vector<int> x = foo();
vector<int>::const_iterator iter2;
stringstream buffer;
for(iter2 = x.begin(); iter2 != x.end(); ++iter2) 
{
   buffer  << *iter << " ";    
}
// To remove the extra trailing space, not sure if it is needed or not
string elements = buffer.str().substr(0,buffer.str().length()-1);

rowvec a = rowvec(elements.c_str());
```

As per the [Armadillo Documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) rowvec's constructor will take a arma::rowvec, a arma::mat, a string (read const char*) or an initialiser list if you are using C++11.